# Does this surface exist

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Does anybody of you know if there is a surface with first fundamental form $(g_{ij}) = \operatorname{diag}(1, \cos^2(u))$ and second fundamental form $(h_{ij}) = \operatorname{diag}(1, \sin^2(u))$? This look somehow very similar to a sphere, but I could not find an explicit representation of this surface. I.e. maybe anybody of you could prove or disprove the existence of this surface as a an immersion $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: The gaussian curvature would be $\tan^2 u$ which is far from the shape of a sphere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory. Locally, the Codazzi and Gauss equations are necessary and sufficient to get such an immersion. Here they fail, as I leave it to you to check.